# Add .framwork to a Swift Package?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a Swift package I would like to make public, however I do not want the source code for all of the files shared.

My solution was to bundle the private source code into a .framework and have the swift package call the private source code.

However I cannot seem to be able to add the .framework into the Swift Package project. Any help?

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? It's an actual problem that is being fixed in SPM. I'd bet a common issue for most people

Comment: Maybe because it is kind of a duplicate? There have been a lot of similar questions the last couple of months.

Comment: I searched, none fit this criteria. But whoever marked it -1 please post why and the duplicate links so others can follow them also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an accepted proposal for binary dependencies in SwiftPM. So when that feature ships you will be able to zip up your framework, if it is an xcframework, and link against it. Until then you can only use unsafe linker flags to do so which means you can’t use the package with Xcode unless it is a local package.